# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments returns null for one ClickOnce application but not the other

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two WinForm ClickOnce applications initially developed with Visual Studio Express 2008 (C#) and now maintained using VS Express 2013. Both target the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

Please consider the code below where I try to get ActivationArguments by inserting the one line of code after InitializeComponent() and clicking Start in VS to run and debug the application:

```
public Form1()
{ 
    InitializeComponent();                
    ActivationArguments actArgs = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments;
    etc...
}
```

I'm stumped as to why one application returns null for ActivationArguments while the other returns the expected object. Both are straightforward WinForm applications, straightforward C#, same deployment settings, nothing fancy. The goal is to eventually get ActivationData but I first need an ActivationArguments object to get there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The following applies to a C# WinForms App .Net 4.5 that uses ClickOnce Publishing for an application that is set to be "..available offline as well.." in the Publish Settings of the project.

1) CommandLine arguments specified in the Project Settings or passed from a console can be either read in program.cs by adding args to the main()

```
static void Main(string[] args) // in program.cs, args[0] is first argument
```

or by using

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(); // in Form1.cs e.g. in Form1_Load, args[1] is first argument
```

2) CommandLine arguments passed by e.g. double clicking an associated file in Explorer/Desktop can be read like this:

```
using System.Deployment.Application;

// e.g. in Form1_Load
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    string[] activationData = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData;
    if (activationData != null && activationData.Length > 0)
    {
        string[] args = activationData[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            // args[0] is first argument
        }
    }
}
```