# Why AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments is null?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, appdomain, file-association

I have set up the File Associations in project property, Publish--> Options--> File Associations, Extension is .abc, then when I double click the file xy.abc, my application launches, but why AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments is null?

Do I miss anything or any place I should check for the issue?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073608/appdomain-currentdomain-setupinformation-activationarguments-returns-null-for-on